# Десериализация из XML-файла с использованием Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, десериализация

Есть xml-файл:

```xml
<MB>
    <SimpleBean>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>12</y>
    </SimpleBean>
</MB>
```

Вот класс в который передаю элементы:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "MB", allowGetters= true)
public class SimpleBean {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Можно как-то пропустить элемент MB, аннотация JsonIgnoreProperties не помогает, вылетает с ошибкой:

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "SimpleBeat" (class parceCurrent.vo.SimpleBean), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "x", "y"]).

Пробовал использовать `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`, проходит без ошибок, но ничего не читает.

Comment: Для такой задачи можно использовать потоковый (StAX) XmlReader. Он читает xml, пропускает один (или несколько) элементов. А дальше подаём этот ридер на вход десериализатору.

Comment: т.е. так эту проблему ни как не решить?
либо использовать парсер, либо создавать еще одни класс?

Comment: В .NET/C# создание потокового ридера делается одной строкой и пропуск узлов - ещё одной. Итого две строки кода дополнительно к десериализатору. В Java много библиотек для работы с xml, я лишь некоторые знаю, да и то поверхностно. Поэтому не могу сходу сказать, как лучше и проще сделать.

Comment: В используемом десериализаторе есть события реагирования на незнакомые узлы XML? Опять же, сужу по моему опыту C#: там есть такое событие в стандартном XmlSerializer. В этом событии можно пропустить (не маппить) неизвестный узел (который не совпадает с моделью класса).